# How do I use the Dart analyzer class to build a tree instance that reflects the AST?

Tags: dart, abstract-syntax-tree, analyzer, decomposition

I would like to use the `analyzer` package to parse the widget tree that's defined in the `build` function and automagically factor the code for each method invocation into separate methods.

Pretend the sample input below contains a massive widget tree that needs to be decomposed, ideally based on the `child` and `children` properties. In the example, I'd like to navigate into the `MyApp` class declaration, into the `build` method declaration, into the `return MaterialApp...` return statement and then to each named expression in that function, such as `theme`, `home`, etc.

However, I'm not sure how to constrain the `AstVisitor` in such a way that allows me to follow the AST down a specific path and not just visit all the nodes in the tree for that type. The `AstVisitor` documentation also doesn't guarantee the order that it walks the tree, meaning I can reconstruct the widget tree in a deterministic way.

Am I going about this all wrong?

Sample input:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Foo Bar Baz')),
          body: null,
        ));
  }
}
```

My code:

```
class _BuildMethodVisitor extends RecursiveAstVisitor<UINode> {
  final UINode root;

  _BuildMethodVisitor(this.root) : super();

  @override
  UINode? visitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclaration node) {
    print('classDeclaration::${node.name}');

    super.visitClassDeclaration(node);

    return null;
  }

  @override
  UINode? visitReturnStatement(ReturnStatement node) {
    print('returnStatement::${node}');

    super.visitReturnStatement(node);

    return null;
  }

  @override
  UINode? visitNamedExpression(NamedExpression node) {
    print('namedExpression::${node}');

    super.visitNamedExpression(node);

    return null;
  }

  @override
  UINode? visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocation node) {
    print('methodInvocation::${node}');

    super.visitMethodInvocation(node);

    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest interface for that is probably a [custom_lint](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_lint) with a code fix.  Remi put a lot of work on making lints and refactorings easier and workarounds for things that were not as well designed.  You might check that out in your pursuits.